# Add new rows in R dataframe to fill time gaps

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 2),
  time_0  = c(2, 3, 6), 
  time_1 = c(4, 5, 8), 
  event = 1, 
  time_end = 10)

df
#>   id time_0 time_1 event time_end
#> 1  1      2      4     1       10
#> 2  2      3      5     1       10
#> 3  2      6      8     1       10
```

For each `id`, `time_0` is the time `event` starts, and `time_1` is the time `event` ends. `event` repeats in `id` 2. The follow-up time is from 0 to 10. The data frame only includes periods when event occurred. I would like to fill the `event` free (`event = 0`) periods during the follow-up time. For example, `id` 1, `event` is 0 from 0 (`time_0`) to 2 (`time_1`), and again from 4 (`time_0`) to 10 (`time_1).

The expected data frame like:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  time_0  = c(0, 2, 4, 0, 3, 5, 6, 8), 
  time_1 = c(2, 4, 10, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10), 
  event = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),  
  time_end = 10)
df_1
#>   id time_0 time_1 event time_end
#> 1  1      0      2     0       10
#> 2  1      2      4     1       10
#> 3  1      4     10     0       10
#> 4  2      0      3     0       10
#> 5  2      3      5     1       10
#> 6  2      5      6     0       10
#> 7  2      6      8     1       10
#> 8  2      8     10     0       10
```

I have searched SO posts and there are many similar questions but I still have not identified the right one yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please share your original `df` and its difference vs `df_2`? I don't see what logic you're using to insert the `event = 0` rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
m <- data.frame(id = 0 , time_0 = 0, time_1 = 0)
k <- 1
for(i in unique(df$id)){
    x <- sort(unique(c(0 , unlist(subset(df , id == i)[,2:3]) , 10)))
    for(j in 1:(length(x)-1)){
        m[k,] <- c(i , x[j] , x[j+1])
        k <- k + 1
    }
}

ans <- merge(m , df , by = c("id" , "time_0" , "time_1") , all.x = T)

ans$event <- ifelse(is.na(ans$event) , 0 , ans$event)
ans$time_end <- 10
ans
```

- output

```
  id time_0 time_1 event time_end
1  1      0      2     0       10
2  1      2      4     1       10
3  1      4     10     0       10
4  2      0      3     0       10
5  2      3      5     1       10
6  2      5      6     0       10
7  2      6      8     1       10
8  2      8     10     0       10
```